# Matrix Power and Power Incorrect in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: matrices, inverse, wolfram-alpha

When computing the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1 & -\sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{3} & 1\end{bmatrix} times its inverse, Wolfram Alpha produces this incorrect [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%5B%7B%7B1%2C-Sqrt%5B3%5D%7D%2C%7BSqrt%5B3%5D%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2C-Sqrt%5B3%5D%7D%2C%7BSqrt%5B3%5D%2C1%7D%7D). The same [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixPower%5B%7B%7B1%2C-Sqrt%5B3%5D%7D%2C%7BSqrt%5B3%5D%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2C-Sqrt%5B3%5D%7D%2C%7BSqrt%5B3%5D%2C1%7D%7D) happens when Power is changed to MatrixPower. I suspect that this is a parsing problem, that somehow Power/MatrixPower is interpreted as something else. Normally, negative power is interpreted as inverses according to the [documentation center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html). Likewsie, if I change Power to Inverse, it also produces the correct result. As far as I know, it is also not taking the inverse of each individual elements in the matrix, and adding parathesese or brackets around the first term does not change the result.

I have also tried some other examples: [example 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixPower%5B%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D), [example 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixPower%5B%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D). What exactly is Wolfram Alpha treating MatrixPower($m,-1$) as?

Comment: You might get better answers on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ . Cheers

Comment: You forgot the dot between the two factors to make sure the matrix product is computed.

Comment: Default product is Hadamard product...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's computing the inverse correctly, but doing the product elementwise.
Try power[{{1,-Sqrt[3]},{Sqrt[3],1}},-1] . {{1,-Sqrt[3]},{Sqrt[3],1}}.

Comment: Thank you very much!